# Unable to access organisations's IAM and audit logs pages in Google Cloud

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform

I have been granted the "Security reviewer" role for my organization on Google Cloud Platform. Accorind to this page (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#iam-roles) security reviewer has resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy permission. However, when I visit the IAM or audit logs pages, I receive the error "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page". On the bottom of the error page, it states that

"Minimum permissions required for this page:

```
resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy
```

All permissions checked for the current organization:

```
resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy
resourcemanager.organizations.setIamPolicy"
```

I should have fulfilled the Minimum permissions required.

Does it mean I also resourcemanager.organizations.setIamPolicy in order to view these pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since those roles are granted at Organization Level, I would suggest to add the Organization Viewer role to your user and thus he can view all project's IAM menu in the Cloud Console.

The Organization Viewer role is part of the [Resource Manager Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles) and it provides access to view an organization and you should be able to explore the IAM in each project that is under your organization.